# Detecting browser support for input type=date using Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, browser-detection

I'm not sure what's the right way to detect whether or not the browser supports `<input type="date">` using Angular2+

At https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date they suggest creating the input and testing its type using direct DOM access (`createElement`), which I doubt I should do.

Answer (score 0):

In mentioned example no jQuery is used, but pure JS, so you can freely use it within your ts files:

```
// test whether a new date input falls back to a text input or not
let test = document.createElement('input');
test.type = 'date';
// if it does, run the code inside the if() {} block
if (test.type === 'text') {
  // date input not supported
}
else {
  // date input supported
}
```

Comment: Very sorry, I didn't mean JQuery, I meant direct DOM access. I will edit the question.

Comment: You can try to use `Renderer 2` experimental class with its methods like `createElement()`, `setProperty()`, etc... which should work on WebWorkers as well